# Durable product not visible in-app purchase wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In My app i am unable to get "Durable" product list info in Wp 8. With the same code of lines I am getting consumable product list.

```
ListingInformation li = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
var len = li.ProductListings.Count;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Count: " + len);
//var value = li.ProductListings.Values;
foreach(string key in li.ProductListings.Keys) {
    ProductListing pListing = li.ProductListings[key];
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(key);
    string status = Store.CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[key].IsActive ? "Purchased" : pListing.FormattedPrice;
}
```

Where i am making mistake? Pls help...

Comment: I got the problem. It is OS Problem. In WP8 if Durable Product License Duration is **"Forever"** then product will appear in product list when 'CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync()' method is called other wise return nothing if License duration is 1 day,2 days etc. It will work correctly in WP8.1.